# Getting access token live time from program

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am writing an Accesstoken Builder based on this 
[msf4j example](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/samples/jwt-claims/JWTAccessTokenBuilder). I do some filtering on roles and so on. I am using wso2is 5.8
I try to access the AccessTokenValidityPeriod set for the serviceprovider.
In my serviceprovider setup I have increased the "User Access Token Expiry Time", "Application Access Token Expiry Time" and "Id Token Expiry Time".

I can access the value of the token lifetime from the identity.xml file, but I want to lookup the specific settings for this serviceprovider.
My code looks like this

```java
private long getLifetimeInMillis(OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext reqMessageContext, OAuthTokenReqMessageContext ctx) {
        long lifetimeInMillis = -1;
        if (reqMessageContext != null) {
            log.debug("Get lifetime from OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext property");
            lifetimeInMillis = reqMessageContext.getAccessTokenValidityPeriod(); 
/* always returns 0
... */
```

But this always returns 0.
I have debugged the OAuthAuthzReqMessageContext class, but only the Constructor is called an not the setter setAccessTokenValidityPeriod.
My pom.xml contains:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.387</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.inbound.auth.oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.168</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add more information about the msf4j sample you have referred and what is the use case you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I added some information. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get access token validity period use the following approach.

> OAuth2AuthorizeReqDTO
>   authorizationReqDTO=reqMessageContext.getAuthorizationReqDTO();
>
> SpOAuth2ExpiryTimeConfiguration spTimeConfigObj =
>   OAuth2Util.getSpTokenExpiryTimeConfig(authorizationReqDTO..getConsumerKey(),
>   IdentityTenantUtil.getTenantId(authorizationReqDTO.getUser().getTenantDomain()));
>
> validityPeriodInMillis =
>   spTimeConfigObj.getUserAccessTokenExpiryTime();

Thanks

Comment: getSpTokenExpiryTimeConfig() is marked as deprecated and the SpOAuth2ExpiryTimeConfiguration  only contains nulls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a JWT access token in WSO2 Identity Server, you don't need to write any custom code in the latest releases. OAuth2/OIDC configs have this option to configure. See the bottom of the screenshot attached. So you don't need to have the JWTAccessTokenBuilder in the first place.

[image]

Comment: I tried to configure jwt token as descriped [link] (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider) but this doesn't work. Can you point me to an example how to configure it correctly? I want the token to contain keys with domain (f.e.http://smartfacts.com/claims/ID). Furthermore I want filter the groups to reuce token-size if the user is meber in many groups and transform the group name from Application/MIDAdmin to MIDAdmin.

Comment: Since oidc has well defined user attribute names, you cannot use other names. You can do application - idp role mapping from the roles and permissions section.